# Unable to use external javascript file with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-tools

My HTML file works and whenever I attach the script directly into my HTML body or head tag, the script runs properly. However, when I attach it separately using `<script src="app.js"></script>`, it doesn't work.
I have been trying to figure out why and nothing seems to work.

Please help.
Thank You.

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Projectz</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.2/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <style>
      * {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #ebebeb;
        margin: 10px;
      }

      #container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 2em;
      }

      .buttons {
        background-color: #ebebeb;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow:  5px 5px 8px #c8c8c8,
             -5px -5px 8px #ffffff;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 6px;
        transition: 0.4s;
      }
      .buttons:hover {
        background-color: #dadada;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #profilePicture {
        visibility: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 4px solid #00a2ff;
        float: right;
        width: 3vw;
        height: 3vw;
        justify-self: end;
      }

      #googleIcon{
        width: 4vw;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 8px;
      }

      #googleIcon:hover {
        background-color: #dadada;
      }

      #loginButton img {
        transition: 0.4s;
      }

      #loginButton:hover img {
        background-color: #dadada;
      }

      .url {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        background-color: #ebebeb;
        z-index: 1;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;    
        padding: 2em;     
        margin: -2em; 
      }

      #loginPage a {
        transition: 0.4s;
      }

      #loginPage:hover a {
        background-color: #dadada;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <button id="loginButton" class="buttons">
        <img src="img/googleTransparent.png" alt="google icon" id=googleIcon>
      </button>
  
      <button id="signOutButton" class="buttons">
        Sign Out
      </button>
  
      <button id="emailAndPass" class="buttons">
        Login
      </button>
  
      <button id="createAccount" class="buttons">
        Create Account
      </button>

      <button class="buttons" id="loginPage">
        <a href="login.html" class="url">Login Page</a>
      </button>

      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <img id="profilePicture">
    </div>

    <h1 id="personName"></h1>
    <h2 id="userEmail"></h2>
    <h3 id="userUID"></h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

## app.js

```
import { default as firebase } from "firebase";

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    appId: "xxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    const app = firebase.app();
    console.log(app);

    let personName = document.getElementById("personName");
    let profilePicture = document.getElementById("profilePicture");
    let userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail");
    let userUID = document.getElementById("userUID");
    let state;

    //signing out
    document.getElementById("signOutButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        personName.innerHTML = "You have signed out";
        console.log('Signed Out');
        state = 0;
        console.log(state);
      }, function(error) {
        console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
      });
    })

    //logging in
    document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
      const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then(result => {
          const userName = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName
          personName.innerHTML = "Hello " + userName;
          state = 1;
          console.log(state);
          profilePicture.setAttribute('src', firebase.auth().currentUser.photoURL);
          userEmail.innerHTML = "Email: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
          userUID.innerHTML = "UID: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
          profilePicture.style.visibility = "visible";
        });

    });
  });
```

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: @Ajay No error on the console

Comment: Try putting  the `<script src="app.js"></script>` at the end of the the `body`

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try to include those firebase libs from a CDN? and remove the line from app.js: `import {...} from "firebase"`

Comment: It works now when I removed the import